# What's the recommended way to represent distributions of complex-valued random variables in Tensorflow Probability?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't see any existing classes for complex Normal or complex Wishart distributions in the Tensorflow Probability api docs. Is this because it's easy to synthesize these distributions from existing apis? If so I would appreciate an example or a reference.